# Fastreport select fields to print

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have a report where I would like to select which field of database to show/print and hide all unselected field.I had seen in Fastreport demo but its only Choosing records to print. By the way i'm using dbexpress connection and firebird for database.

Any one who has some ideas about this?

Comment: See frxStdWizard.pas code

Comment: You may convert it to script but this is not easy task like "Choosing records to print"

Comment: It's easy , just find the `TfrxMemoView` you want to show and set `Visible` property to `True` , or you can create your custom report programmatically as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another simple solution would be to solve it on Delphi itself, before calling your Report.

Just add a calculated field to your dataset, and make it return the content of the real field that you want to show on your report. Now you can link your Report to that calculated field, and each time it will present the field that you have selected to present.